# CI4 - Error al enviar correos - MessageFormatter::formatMessage(): Creating message formatter failed

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Buen dia

Estoy usando la librería email de codeigniter4, el correo se llega a enviar (llega al destinatario) pero aparece el siguiente error:

> MessageFormatter::formatMessage(): Creating message formatter failed
>
> SYSTEMPATH/Language/Language.php at line 248

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['SMTPHost'] = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
    $config['SMTPUser'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['SMTPPass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['SMTPPort'] = 25;
    $config['SMTPCrypto'] = 'tls';
    $config['mailType'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['CRLF'] = "\r\n";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

    $email = \Config\Services::email();
    $email->initialize($config);

    $email->setFrom('no-reply@prueba.com');
    $email->setTo('prueba@prueba.com');
    $email->setSubject('Asunto de Prueba');
    $email->setMessage('Texto de Prueba...');
        
    $email->send();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Saludos